# Curses-based SQLite console browser

Tags: linux, command-line, sqlite

There are programs like *sqlitebrowser* that let you view databases as tables and edit them in a convenient way. But I can't encounter a similar program for linux console. I have a server that I can access via SSH, and having a ***convenient database browser*** for Linux console would be beneficial to me.

Is there such a program offering terminal-compatible "graphical" UI? It could be based on e.g. curses/ncurses/unicurses.

Example for another database engine/OS: [image]

Comment: What's wrong with the `sqlite3` executable – or, put into other words, what features do you need it doesn't offer? I could think of e.g. ncurses support or the like (to provide a kind of GUI – see e.g. [SQLite Commander](https://github.com/psankar/sqlite-commander)), but I cannot tell what you've got in mind :)

Comment: @Izzy well, basically, I was looking for something that could be based on curses/ncurses/unicurses. I'll take a look at this SQLite Commander, it might be just what I need.

Comment: Good luck! And don't forget letting us know of the outcome ;)

Answer (score 8):

My choice for browsing tabular data in the console or terminal is [Visidata] (https://www.visidata.org). It works well with SQLite and a variety of other data sources. It does allow editing data in the cells of a table, but is not great for tasks like altering table structures. It does **not** allow running SQL queries, but is very efficient in browsing data and manipulating it in  a variety of ways.

Comment: Welcome James! Excellent answer quality. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Check the [sqlectron](https://sqlectron.github.io/). It comes both in GUI and in Term version.

Also there is [sqlcrush](https://github.com/coffeeandscripts/sqlcrush).

Answer (score 3):

The SQLite package includes the [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) command-line client, which appears to offer equivalent functionality to `mysql` (MySQL), `psql` (PostgreSQL) or `sqlplus` (Oracle). I don't see that it supports network connection, but that is really outside the intended use-case for SQLite and is unnecessary if you have SSH access to the server.

Comment: Unfortunate timing, but apparently the asker is looking for something curses-based, I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: The problem is that sqlite3 is based on typing commands, not "console GUI", so to say. I want something where I can navigate my table with arrow keys, press enter to edit an entry, etc.